# Can't Upgrade from 10.10-11.04

Tags: 11.04, 10.10, upgrade

When trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 10.10 to Ubuntu 11.04 I got this error during update

```
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
, E:Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have no clue about computers.

Answer (score 1):

open update manager , click at settings . It will open a new window . In the window from Ubuntu software TAB at Download from , change your mirror to best server and try again .